# use of a join and a fork node in sequence in activity diagram?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I have to make an activity diagram for a hair salon scenario, I think it may be bad practice or even fully incorrect to use a join node and a fork node straight after one another as I have done.

Is this allowed?

[image: Activity diagram here]

Answer (score 3):

Those join nodes will hang forever, waiting for the paths not taken from the decision nodes to offer tokens. Replace them with merge nodes.

To be able to make correct activity models, you should read Conrad Bock's six-part series of articles on the UML 2 Activity and Action Model, especially [part 6](https://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2003_11/column1.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the response I will definitely give that a read, sorry but can you please clarify what you mean by "hang forever"?

Comment: Neither will receive the tokens needed to proceed in an execution.

Comment: oops. Didn't see your answer...

Comment: @samcawly e.g. the top right decision sends only one token  to whatever is ungarded but the join bar needs two to continue. Similarly the other one. Replace the join bar with a diamond and you're good to go. Undeleted my answer...

Answer (score 0):

That won't work. You will have either dry-cut or washed. So the following join will always get only one token, but needs 2 to continue. Replace it with a diamond-shaped merge node and it's ok.

Comment: I think by “diamond-join” you mean “merge node”.

Comment: @JimL. Sure, I was thinking that the OP would understand that better, Will use another wording